# How to specify either empty snapshot_identifier or a datasource value

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-aurora

I am trying to make a common module to allow an rds cluster to be built - however I want to be able to choose to have it build from either a snapshot or from scratch.

I used a `count` to choose whether to perform the datasource lookup or not which works. However if it is set to 0 and doesn't run, the resource will fail as it doesn't know what `data.aws_db_cluster_snapshot.latest_cluster_snapshot`. Is there a way around this that I can't quite think of myself?

**Datasource**:

```
data "aws_db_cluster_snapshot" "latest_cluster_snapshot" {
  count                 = "${var.enable_restore == "true" ? 1 : 0}"
  db_cluster_identifier = "${var.snapshot_to_restore_from}"
  most_recent           = true
}
```

**Resource**:

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "aurora_cluster" {
  ...
  snapshot_identifier = "${var.enable_restore == "false" ? "" : data.aws_db_cluster_snapshot.latest_cluster_snapshot.id}"
  ...
}
```

**Versions**:

Terraform v0.11.10

- provider.aws v2.33.0

Comment: What version of Terraform are you using?

Comment: Apologies. I usually include that. Updated the original post.

Comment: Anything stopping you moving to 0.12? 0.12 adds support for lazily evaluating which would make this work.

Comment: Nothing is outright stopping me (other than having a lot of work to implement). If there isn't a way to achieve it in 0.11.x then I suppose I will have to upgrade.